# How to fix 'Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames'

Tags: node.js, https, ssl-certificate

I have a problem when I run get a response for service. There are two services. For the first service, it's working perfectly but in the second I have issue "Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Cert is empty". When I used Postman with certificates its works perfectly. What should I set or implement to make it works?​

I tried using: checkServerIdentity, rejectUnauthorized: true.

```
let options = {
    hostname: 'ws.aaa.bbb.nn',
    path: '/api',
    method: 'GET',
    key: fs.readFileSync('/private.crt'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/public.crt'),
    passphrase: '***'
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    let body = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk)=> {
        body += chunk;
        console.log(body)
    });
});
```

Should be status code 200.

Comment: Same error for me- have you solved it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you got a bad certificate.
Get a correct one or just turn the SSL certificate verification off.

Comment: I have to say that this answer helped me getting the requests on a stage environment to work where we do not have a valid SSL cert. I have to admit that I do not understand the question completely But if the question is saying "How can I make the requests work when I do not have a valid cert" this answer was fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, Just try to set Authorization Type to "Inherit auth from parent".